# how to migrate or copy SSRS datasource from one server to another without restoring the report server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to migrate SSRS report from SQL 2008r2 to SQL 2014 server. I used reportsync to transfer the report to the server. the reports are successfully transferred but however the roles subscriptions and datasources are not transferred. Is there is any way to copy or migrate the data sources, roles and subscription from one server to another without restoring the report server database?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have used these migration tools which doesn't help me much.
i found the below link after a lot of struggle trying different things

https://azuresql.codeplex.com/releases/view/115207

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn531017.aspx#bkmk_how_to_use_the_script

better to test reports and subscription after migrate finish

Comment: I had great success with this script - it does require both servers to be running and 'connectable'.  It is also clearly documented that encrypted data needs to be put in - in other words, any data sources that include a password need to be modified to reenter the password.  All the other connection attributes came across

Comment: Thanks for the MSDN link.  The 'ssrs_migration.rss' file is found on GitHub, https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/features/reporting-services/ssrs-migration-rss.